# Dynamically uncheck multiple select options in md-select angular 4.x

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, md-select

I am trying to implement on click of a button in mat-select multiple, an option should get unchecked and should be removed from the checked list too.

for removing the selected option I have written my code as below :

mat-select Option:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <mat-select class="multiple-location-list-search-wrapper full-width" #mulLoc required placeholder="Locations" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let l of locationsBasedOnPropertyType; let i = index" class="multiple-field-box" [hidden]="tempLocations[i]"
              [value]="l">
              {{ l.value }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Delete button:

```
<span (click)="deleteLocation(i, mulLoc);">Delete Location</span>
          <p>
            <strong>{{mulLoc.value[i].value}}</strong>
          </p>
```

Delete function:

```
  deleteLocation(index, multipleLocation){
    multipleLocation.selected[index]._selected = false;
    multipleLocation.selected[index]._active = false;
    multipleLocation.selected.splice(index,1);
    multipleLocation.value.splice(index,1);
  }
```

By Implementing above, I am able to delete option from `selected` & `value` array but it's not reflecting in Material UI. Location option is not getting unchecked.

Is there any Hack or internal Method to do the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Will Howel, Thanks for your help man.

But I got my solution Like below:

I did some research in 
`'..app-folder../node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts'` 
I found 
`writeValue(value: any): void;`

The changes I made in my view :

```
<mat-select class="full-width" #mulLoc required placeholder="Locations" multiple [(ngModel)]="resLoc" name="resLoc">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let l of locations; let i = index [hidden]="tempLocations[i]" [value]="l">
{{ l.value }}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Objects :

```
locations = [
{id : 'IND',value : 'india'},
{id : 'INS',value : 'indonesia'},
{id : 'THL',value : 'thailand'}
]
resLoc = [locations[0], locations[2]]
```

Component : this is the function which I am calling for deleting(unselecting) location

```
deleteLocation(i,mulLoc) {
    this.resLoc.splice(i,1); // my ngModel
    mulLoc.writeValue(this.resLoc); // reference variable of mat-select
  }
```

Hope it helps! happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I don't fully understand how and when the options are deleted, but here's an example that seems to fulfill your need

```
toppings = new FormControl();

toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];

remove(topping: string) {
  // Remove from form control value
  const selectedIndex = this.toppings.value && this.toppings.value.indexOf(topping)
  if (selectedIndex > -1) {
    const newToppingsValue = this.toppings.value.slice();
    newToppingsValue.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    this.toppings.setValue(newToppingsValue);
  }

  // Remove from topping list
  const listIndex = this.toppingList.indexOf(topping);
  if (listIndex > -1) {
    this.toppingList.splice(listIndex, 1);
  }

}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-sfemkt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

EDIT: Here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-ygj9vj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) where the option isn't removed, just deselected.

Comment: I don't want to remove the option, I just want to uncheck it.

Comment: Hm ok, how about [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-ygj9vj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: The uncheck example was perfect for me.